# [AS3][GAME] Can't find framelabel null in scène null

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a memory game (card matching game) and all works well the first time the game is set up, but when the game "resets" I gett the following error:

**ArgumentError: Error #2109: Can't find framelabel null in scène null.
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at main/omdraaien()
        at main/omdraaien()[memory1_0\main.as:138]**

this is my whole code.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Remy&Mark
     */
    // door te 'extenden' maak je van main (in dit geval) een sub-class van Sprite,
    // dus kan je alle voor-gedefiniëerde functies die "sprite" heeft gebruiken.
    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        var kaart1:MovieClip;
        var kaarten:Array; // ARRAY is een table.
        var pause_timer:Timer;
        var kaart1open:Boolean;
        var kaart2open:Boolean;
        var kaart1value:Number;
        var kaart2value:Number;
        var kaart1id:Number;
        var kaart2id:Number;
        var cardsRemoved:Number;
        var button:Sprite;
        var values:Array = new Array(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10);
        var startknop:MovieClip = new startKnop();
        var tryAgain:MovieClip = new taKnop(); // try again.
        var score:TextField = new TextField();
        var result:TextField = new TextField(); // WIN of LOSE.
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var streak:Number;
        var bonus:Number;
        var klok:MovieClip = new clock();
        var gameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 5); 
        var retry:Boolean = false; // dit duidt aan of het voor het eerst begint of dat het wordt geretried.


        public function main()
        {
            // dit maakt de startknop
            startknop.x = 100;
            startknop.y = 200;
            startknop.buttonMode = true;
            startknop.useHandCursor = true;
            startknop.mouseChildren = false;
            addChild(startknop);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
            // einde
        }

        private function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(1);
            bonus = 0;
            streak = 0;
            if (retry == false)
            {
                removeChild(startknop);
            } else {
                removeChild(tryAgain);
            }
            // score
            score.x = 250;
            score.y = 30;
            score.width = 250;
            score.text = "Score: 0";
            format.size = 40;
            score.setTextFormat(format);
            addChild(score);
            // einde
            // game klok
            klok.x = 625;
            klok.y = 100;
            addChild(klok);
            gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, lose);
            gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
            gameTimer.start();
            // einde
            legKaarten();
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,startGame);
        }

        private function legKaarten() 
        {
            cardsRemoved = 0;
            kaart1open = false;
            kaart2open = false;
            kaart1value = 0;
            kaart2value = 0;
            kaart1id = 0;
            kaart2id = 0;
            kaarten = new Array(); // je roept hier een lege Array(table) op.
            for (var i:int = 0; i <= 17; i++ ) // (int)eger is een afgerond getal. ( geen decimalen)
            {
                var real:int = i; 
                var kolom:int = i;
                var rij:int = 0;
                kaarten.push(new Kaart1()); // push voegt een waarde aan een array toe.
                addChild(kaarten[i]);
                kaarten[i].stop();
                if ( real > 5&&real <= 11)
                {
                    rij++;
                    kolom = i - 6;
                } 
                if ( real > 11)
                {
                    rij = rij + 2;
                    kolom = i - 12;
                }
                var randIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length); // je moet een int maken van de random, anders werkt het niet.
                kaarten[i].id = i;
                kaarten[i].value = values[randIndex]; // dit geeft een kaart een random value uit de Array.
                values.splice(randIndex, 1); // dit haalt een value uit de Array values.
                kaarten[i].x = 200+(kolom * 80);
                kaarten[i].y = 100 + (rij * 150);
                kaarten[i].width = 75;
                kaarten[i].height = 125;
                kaarten[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, omdraaien);
            }
        }
        // hier maken we die 'private' functie, kan alleen in dit bestand worden opgeroepen.
        private function omdraaien(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var geklikteKaart:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip; // e.target is de mouseklik die hij binnenkrijgt.
            if (geklikteKaart.currentFrame == 1 && kaart1open == false)
            {
                if (kaart1open == false)
                {
                    geklikteKaart.gotoAndStop(geklikteKaart.value); // line 138
                    kaart1open = true;
                    kaart1value = geklikteKaart.value;
                    kaart1id = geklikteKaart.id;
                }
            }
            else if(geklikteKaart.currentFrame == 1 && kaart1open == true && kaart2open == false)
            {
                geklikteKaart.gotoAndStop(geklikteKaart.value);
                kaart2open = true;
                kaart2value = geklikteKaart.value;
                kaart2id = geklikteKaart.id;
            }
            if (kaart1open == true && kaart2open == true && kaart1value == kaart2value)
            {
                pause_timer = new Timer(500, 1);
                pause_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeKaarten);
                pause_timer.start();
            }
            else if (kaart1open == true && kaart2open == true && kaart1value != kaart2value)
            {
                pause_timer = new Timer(500, 1);
                pause_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, resetKaarten);
                pause_timer.start();
            }
        }
        private function removeKaarten(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            removeChild(kaarten[kaart1id]);
            removeChild(kaarten[kaart2id]);
            streak ++;
            cardsRemoved ++;
            kaart1open = false;
            kaart2open = false;
            kaart1value = 0;
            kaart2value = 0;
            kaart1id = 0;
            kaart2id = 0;
            if (streak > 1)
            {
                bonus = bonus + 50;
            }
            score.text = "Score: " + (cardsRemoved * 100 + bonus);
            format.size = 40;
            score.setTextFormat(format);
            pause_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeKaarten);
        }
        private function resetKaarten(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            kaarten[kaart1id].gotoAndStop(1);
            kaarten[kaart2id].gotoAndStop(1);
            kaart1open = false;
            kaart2open = false;
            kaart1value = 0;
            kaart2value = 0;
            kaart1id = 0;
            kaart2id = 0;
            streak = 0;
            pause_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, resetKaarten);
        }
        private function tick(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            klok.wijzer.rotation += 360 / gameTimer.repeatCount;
        }
        private function lose(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            retry = true;
            removeChild(klok);
            removeChild(score);
            // tekst voor verlies
            result.x = 300;
            result.y = 150;
            result.width = 250;
            result.text = "YOU SUCK!";
            format.size = 40;
            result.setTextFormat(format);
            addChild(result);
            // einde
            // dit maakt de try again knop.
            tryAgain.x = 100;
            tryAgain.y = 200;
            tryAgain.buttonMode = true;
            tryAgain.useHandCursor = true;
            tryAgain.mouseChildren = false;
            addChild(tryAgain);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
            // einde
            // hier reset ik de klok
            gameTimer.reset();
            // einde
            // hier worden de overgebleven kaarten verwijderd.
            var kIndex:int = kaarten.length;
            for (var r:int = 0; r < kIndex; r++)
            {
                removeChild(kaarten[r]);
                values.splice(kIndex, 1)
            }
            //einde
        }
    }
}**
```

I have searched alot of topics on different forums but I couldn't find anything that could help me.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: your random index has a flaw.  If Math.random() produces 1, it will produce a value that is out-of-range of your values array

Comment: Most likely your issue stems from line 121: `kaarten[i].value = values[randIndex];` , you should check if the value being assigned is null

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Yes you are right! after the reset the value returns only 0. Could you help me fix this (I'm a starter).

Comment: it's because you're splicing values out of the array, but never putting them back, so eventually your array is empty I think.

Comment: if you just re-initialize your array on app reset, it will probably fix your problem

Comment: Could you show me a quick example how to do that maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue, is that you are splicing items out of your `values` array, but not putting those values back when you reset your game. So when your game restarts, the array is empty.

instead of initializing your values array when you define it, do it in your `startGame` method:

```
var values:Array;  //just declare it here, instead of initializing it here

private function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //initialize it here
    values = new Array(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10);
```

One other thing to note, is you have a flaw in your randomIndex. If Math.random() produces 1, it will produce a value that is out-of-range of your values array, so you want to subtract your values.length by 1:

```
var randIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (values.length - 1))
```

Comment: Ok sure, can't +1 it yet though :s